# Making a vector of pairs, sorting it and then extract the vectors from it

Tags: c++

I have two `std::vector<double>` vectors. I want to make a vector of pairs from them, then sort the it according to the values of first vector; and finally want to extract the sorted vectors from it.

My code for doing it was:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

std::vector<double> new ( std::vector<double> pre,  std::vector<double> post){
                  int n= pre.size();
                  //initialising vector of pairs
                  std::vector< std::pair <double,double> > new;
                  // Entering values in vector of pairs 
                  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                        new.push_back( std::make_pair(pre[i],post[i]) ); 
                  }
                  //sort it
                  sort(new.begin(), new.end());

                  // now extract the elements of sorted paired vector 
                  // and store it in a new vector
                  std::vector<double> newb(n);
                  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                     newb[i] = new[i].first;
                  }

                  return newb;

            }
```

But I am getting the error:

```
main.cpp:15:6: error: 'vector' is not a member of 'std'
      std::vector<double> new ( std::vector<double> pre,  std::vector<double> post){
      ^~~
main.cpp:15:18: error: expected primary-expression before 'double'
      std::vector<double> new ( std::vector<double> pre,  std::vector<double> post){
                  ^~~~~~
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `#include <vector>`.

Comment: But including it gives a new error:  ```` main.cpp:16:26: error: expected unqualified-id before 'new'
      std::vector<double> new ( std::vector<double> pre,  std::vector<double> post){
                          ^~~  ````

Comment: `new` is a C++ keyword! Choose other names!

Comment: Besides, I don't understand why you don't simply sort the `pre` vector, if the vector of pairs is sorted according to the values of the first vector

Comment: Also, you never checked if `pre` and `post` are the same size.  If they're not the same size, you have an out-of-bound access on one of those vectors.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes they are of same size

Comment: @Damien because I have to sort both the vectors according to the first one.

Comment: @gultu -- Off topic, but you will learn quickly not to trust clients calling your code.  You need to explicitly check within that function whether they are the same size.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes I am totally new in C++. still leaning.

Comment: @gultu At least, do this: `int n = std::min(pre.size(), post.size());`

Comment: In this case, it will be slightly more efficient to sort the indices instead of sorting pairs.

Comment: "_I have to sort both the vectors according to the first one_" - But you are not putting the sorted values in the `post` vector (which is also passed-by-value and not reference).

Comment: @TedLyngmo it's the input vector; I named it as post just for the sake of naming it. In my original code, I am putting the sorted values in the post vector

Comment: Ok, but in the code you've shown, the `post` vector is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing these:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::sort
#include <vector>    // std::vector
```

And also, you never return the sorted `post` vector so your vectors don't have any index connection anymore. To be able to return the sorted vectors, pass them by reference to your function.

Instead of creating a vector of pairs, you could sort the indexes and use the sorted indexes to change the values in both vectors. You can use `std::tie` to make the comparison easier.

```
#include <tuple>     // std::tie

void duosort(std::vector<double>& pre, std::vector<double>& post) {
    if(pre.size() != post.size()) throw std::range_error("bork");

    std::vector<size_t> idx;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < pre.size(); ++i) idx.emplace_back(i);

    sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(), [&pre, &post](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
        return std::tie(pre[a], post[a]) < std::tie(pre[b], post[b]);
    });

    // put the values in sorted order according to idx
    std::vector<double> pre_temp(idx.size());
    std::vector<double> post_temp(idx.size());
    for(size_t i = 0; i < idx.size(); ++i) {
        pre_temp[i] = pre[idx[i]];
        post_temp[i] = post[idx[i]];
    }
    pre.swap(pre_temp);
    post.swap(post_temp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing:

```
#include <algorithm> // for sort
#include <vector>
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Also, `new` is an operator so naming your function `new` is unlikely to work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to include appropriate headers:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
```

Next, you would have a trouble with the name "new" which is a reserved keyword. Try to find other names for both the function and the variable.
I would also recommend to pass the vectors by reference:

```
std::vector<double> const &pre, ...
```